# How to install an .app file to unregistered iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

We have bought new iPod touch, I didn't got provisional certificates for this device, I am waiting for approval and adding this device, I have .app for my application I want to load it into my new device. Is it possible? What should I do?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you get your certificates, you won't be able to install unless you jailbrake your device.

Comment: Oh .. then I have to wait :( one more doubt.. In Approved devices without using Xcode how to load our .app?  Anyway?

Comment: You can use the Xcode organizer's context menu "Add Device to Provisioning Portal" to add your device to the approved devices list. However, if you are still awaiting approval this probably won't work.

Comment: @Newbee : 
1. You'll have to drag the Provisioning profile in your iTunes.
2. Then just drag the .app file in iTunes.
3. And sync it with the devices which are already approved and added in the provisioning profile. That's it your app will be install.

Comment: @Rushi In iTunes where do I drop .app, it is not taking

Comment: @Newbee in apps section. Did you drag drop the Provisioning profile first?

Comment: @Rushi Ya I did, from my system where should I take provisioning file? from Keychain?

Comment: @Newbee: Open XCode. Go to Organizer. Go to Devices. You'll see all the provisioning profiles. Just right click on the appropriate one and click Show In Finder.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. You'll have to have the provision profile with your device UDID added to it. Unless you have the Enterprise distribution certificate. Or, your device is jailbrake.

Answer (score 0):

**NO you cant** Get your certificate.

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only in jailbroken iOS device. But if you want to install it in a non-jailbroken device either you need a source or valid provisional certificates for that device.